# Java PhoneBook using ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Im trying to make a PhoneBook using array list but I'm not getting the right output here is my code, thank you for any help with this, the output I'm getting now is just a zero when i ask for the size, not seeming to add anyone, that is probably where the problem lies

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Phonebook implements Directory
{

  private ArrayList<Person> book;

  public Phonebook ()
  {

    book = new ArrayList<Person>();

  }

  /**
   * will return the number of entries currently entered in
   * the <code>Directory</code>.
   * @return - the number of valid entries in the <code>Directory</code>.
   **/
  public int size()
  {
    return book.size();
  }


  /**
   * will display the entries currently entered in the <code>Directory</code>.
   **/
  public void listAll()
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < book.size(); i++)
    {
      System.out.println(book.get(i));
    }
  }


  /**
   * will add a new record to the <code>Directory</code> in alphabetical order
   * if the name is not a duplicate entry.  Otherwise no changes will be made.
   * @param name - name of individual to be added to the <code>Directory</code>.
   * @param number - phone number of the individual to be added.
   * @return - true if the entry was added successfully, otherwise false.
   **/
  public boolean addPerson(String name, String number)
  {
       Person x = new Person (name, number);
       if (checkPerson(name) == -1)
          return false;
       int index = 0;
       while(index < book.size())
       {
        if((x.getName().compareTo((book.get(index)).getName())) < 0)
        {
          book.add(x);
          return true;
        }
        index++;
       }
       return false;
   }



  public int checkPerson(String name)
  {

     int lo = 0;
     int hi = book.size() - 1;
     while(lo <= hi)
     {
       int half = (lo + hi) / 2;
       if(name.equals(book.get(half).getName()))
          return half;
       if(name.compareTo(book.get(half).getName()) < 0){
          hi = half - 1;}
       else lo = half + 1;
     }
     return -1;
  }

  /**
   * will remove an entry from the <code>Directory</code> if the name parameter
   * is currently in the <code>Directory</code>.  Otherwise no changes 
   * will be made.
   * @param name - individual to be removed from the <code>Directory</code>.
   * @return - true if the entry was successfully removed, otherwise false.
   **/
  public boolean removePerson(String name)
  {
     if (checkPerson(name) == -1)
          return false;
     book.remove(checkPerson(name));
     return true;

   }


  /**
   * will search the <code>Directory</code> to find out if the name passed in
   * is currently in the <code>Directory</code>.  If so, it will return the 
   * phone number associated with this person.  Otherwise it will return null.
   * @param name - name of individual to look up in the <code>Directory</code>.
   * @return - the phone number if the name was found, otherwise null.
   **/
  public String lookUp(String name)
  {
    Person n = new Person (name, "999-9999");
    int local = checkPerson(n.getName());
    if(local == -1)
      return null;
    return book.get(local).getNumber();

  }


  /**
   * will search the <code>Directory</code> to find out if the phone number
   * is currently in the <code>Directory</code>.  If so, it will return the 
   * name associated with this number.  Otherwise it will return null.
   * @param number - name of individual to look up in the <code>Directory</code>.
   * @return - the name of the person if the number was found, otherwise null.
   **/

  public String lookUpNum(String number)
  {
    for(int i = 0; i <book.size(); i++)
    {
      if(number.equals(book.get(i).getNumber()))
        return book.get(i).getName();
    }
      return null;
    }

  }
```

/**
 * The  **Person**  class is a container class to hold the
 * name and phone number of an individual.  There are methods
 * to access the name and number, and modify the name and number.
 * Each name is stored in "Last, First" form to facilitate searching
 * and sorting of persons.  A private helper method is used to be
 * sure that names entered in "First Last" form are converted to
 * the proper format.
 */

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person>
{
  private String first;
  private String last;
  private String name;     // Last, First
  private String number;

  /**
   * explicit constructor, will store the first and last
   * names, as well as the entire name in Last, First order
   *
   * @param na is the name of the individual
   * @param nu is the phone number of the individual
   */
  public Person(String na, String nu)
  {
    convert(na);
    number = nu;
  }

  /**
   * copy constructor, will make an exact copy of the parameter
   *
   * @param per is the <B>Person</B> to be duplicated
   */
   public Person(Person per)
  {
    first = per.first;
    last = per.last;
    name = per.name;
    number = per.number;
  }

  /**
   * accessor method to return the name of <B>this Person</B>
   *
   * @return the name of the individual in Last, First order
   */
   public String getName()
  {
    return name;
  }

  /**
   * accessor method to return the phone number of <B>this Person</B>
   *
   * @return the phone number of the individual
   */
  public String getNumber()
  {
    return number;
  }

  /**
   * modifier method to set a new name for <B>this Person</B>
   * The helper method convert() is called to handle the details
   *
   * @param the new name for the individual
   */
  public void setName(String na)
  {
    convert(na);
  }

  /**
   * modifier method to set a new phone number <B>this Person</B>
   * just in case somebody needs to enter witness protection
   *
   * @param the new phone number for the individual
   */
  public void setNumber(String num)
  {
    number = num;
  }

  /**
   * accessor method that implements the <B>Comparable interface</B> 
   * based on the name field for <B>this Person</B>
   * will return a positive number if <B>this</B> is greater than oth
   * zero if <B>this</B> is equal to oth
   * and a negative number if <B>this</B> is less than oth
   *
   * @return negative, zero, or positive int as per Comparable interface
   */
  public int compareTo(Person oth)
  {
    return name.toUpperCase().compareTo(oth.name.toUpperCase());
  }

  /**
   * accessor method to test if the instance data for <B>this Person</B>
   * is equal to the instance data for oth
   *
   * @return true if names and numbers match, false otherwise
   */
  public boolean equals(Person oth)
  {
    return name.toUpperCase().equals(oth.name.toUpperCase()) && number.equals(oth.number);
  }

  private void convert(String na)
  {
    if(na.indexOf(" ") == -1)
    {
      last = na;
      first = null;
      name = na;
    }
    else if(na.indexOf(",") != -1)
    {
      name = na;
      first = na.substring(na.indexOf(",") + 2);
      last = na.substring(na.indexOf(","));
    }
    else
    {
      first = na.substring(0, na.indexOf(" "));
      last = na.substring(na.indexOf(" ") + 1);
      name = last + ", " + first;
    }    

  }

  /**
   * accessor method to return the instance data of <B>this Person</B>
   * in a formatted String (24 character name field, followed by the number)
   *
   * @return name in Last, First order followed by the phone number
   */
  public String toString()
  {
    String local = name;
    if(name.length() < 8)
      local += "\t";
    if(name.length() < 16)
      local += "\t";
    local += "\t" + number;
    return local;
  }
} 


public class client
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Phonebook nickBook = new Phonebook();


    nickBook.addPerson("name lastname", "321-3256");
    System.out.println();
    nickBook.listAll();
    System.out.println(nickBook.size());
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you specify `not getting the right output`? What would be **right** for you? What do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: your `Person.toString()` method does not look right try changing it to something with `String.format()`

Answer (score 1):

Your addPerson method won't add the Person if the list is empty, since `while (0 < 0)` will be false, and the loop won't be entered :

```
   int index = 0;
   while(index < book.size())
   {
    if((x.getName().compareTo((book.get(index)).getName())) < 0)
    {
      book.add(x);
      return true;
    }
    index++;
   }
```

Beside that problem, `book.add(x);` will always add the new `Person` to the end of the List, which is not what you want. You should use `book.add(index,x)`, assuming `index` is the location in which you wish to add the new `Person`.

Finally, if the new Person wasn't added inside the while loop, that means this Person should be the last Person on the List, so you have to add it to the end of the List after the loop.

A possible implementation :

```
  public boolean addPerson(String name, String number)
  {
       Person x = new Person (name, number);
       if (checkPerson(name) == -1)
          return false;
       int index = 0;
       while(index < book.size())
       {
        if((x.getName().compareTo((book.get(index)).getName())) < 0)
        {
          book.add(index,x);
          return true;
        }
        index++;
       }
       book.add(x); // this handles both the case of an empty List and the
                    // case in which the new Person should be the last Person
                    // on the list
       return true;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function `checkPerson` is wrong. `book.size()` is 0 in the beginning and the `hi` results to -1 which means that it does not enter the loop. Besides that think about your `half` variable. It is possible that this results in another number than an integer which is not allowed if you are using this variable as an index for a query of the list.

```
 public int checkPerson(String name)
 {

 int lo = 0;
 int hi = book.size() -1;
 while(lo <= hi)
 {
   int half = (lo + hi) / 2;
   if(name.equals(book.get(half).getName()))
      return half;
   if(name.compareTo(book.get(half).getName()) < 0){
      hi = half - 1;}
   else lo = half + 1;
 }
 return -1;
```

}